# Is there anyway to "ETL" data out of Graphite DB (Grafana)

Tags: graphite, grafana

We are trying to move some of our monitoring away from Grafana / Graphite DB into another system. Is there anyway to pull the full db data into a sql db?

Answer (score 0):

You may use tools delivered from Whisper DB to extract data from files, i.e. and upload it into your DB.

```
[boss@DPU101 gn_bytes_total_card0]$ whisper-fetch gauge.wsp  | head
1499842740      51993482526.000000
1499842800      51014501995.000000
1499842860      51011637567.000000
1499842920      51301789613.000000
1499842980      50994189020.000000
1499843040      50986821344.000000
```

This tool also allows you to extract data in JSON:

```
$ whisper-fetch --help
[...]
--json         Output results in JSON form
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use whisper utilities provided. You need to download it separately using following command.
on Ubuntu 14.04
`apt-get install python-whisper`

whisper-fetch.py program will allow you to download data into json format (or pretty format - separated by tab).
The data points will be for every 60 seconds.

[Whisper Link](https://github.com/graphite-project/whisper)